# How to make a query to get a model with an empty attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model `Foo` that `has_many` `Bar`.
I want a query that returns all `Foos` that have no `Bar`, or empty.
Then I want to apply count or length to see how many Foos doesn't have Bars.

I tried:

```
Foo.where('bars.count = 0').count
Foo.where('bars = []').count
Foo.where('bars.count = ?', 0).count
```

All of them return a Postgresql error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use includes and where to filter only Foo without bars:

```
Foo.includes(:bars).where(bars: {foo_id: nil})
```